# Recieving Ackowledgment after new data insertion in Azure SQL Database

Tags: python, automation, triggers, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

So the situation is that, a person inserts some data into Azure Sql database using some python tool. I want to be notified as soon as the insertion is done, so that the notification can trigger a python code automatically.
My idea is to have my python script that is to be triggered in azure function.

I have two questions :

1. How to recieve notification as soon as insertion is done in the Azure SQL Database.
2. How can it be used to trigger python script using Azure Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "when an item is created" and the "when an item is modified" triggers for SQL in Azure Logic App to react to data changes on tables.

[image]

You can add a condition to the trigger and choose as action calling an Azure Function as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#action-types-list).

For more information about Azure Logic Apps triggers, please read [this](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/) documentation.